# How to access Github API from AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, github-api

I run into the issue that I cannot access https://api.github.com from within an AWS Lambda function on eu-west-1 in Java). Is that by intention? Is it blocked on Github or AWS side? Lambda just fails with a timeout.

How can I access https://api.github.com from a Lambda funktion?

Comment: It sounds like you probably placed your Lambda function in a VPC subnet that doesn't have a NAT gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a Role with Lambda execution and access from VPC fixed it. Found that great resource: https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7

Thanks to Mark B